# Link animation scale to right

Tags: css, animation, css-transforms

I have a link ("a" tag) in my css document, and I have an animation that scales a bottom border out from the center to both ends of the link. I want the animation to scale from the left side and stretch to the right

I have tried using a negative to positive translation on it, but that wasn't looking like I want it to. I can't seem to find any good articles on here, or any other website.

```
a:link:after
{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transition: transform .2s ease-out;
}
a:hover:after
{
    transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

The negative to positive translation doesn't hide the part of the border that hasn't been animated in yet, so there is just a random border to the left of the link.

Comment: You can just use width for this.. 0 normal and on hover 100%

Comment: Btw you can just use height 2px with bg rather than using border with width.. it will work

Comment: That was exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `translate` property in combination with `scale`.

```css
a {
  font-size: 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

a:after {
  content: "";
  background: black;
  height: 2px;
  transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0) scale(0);
  transition: transform .2s ease-out;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

a:hover:after {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale(1);
}
```

```html
<a href="">LINK</a>
```